# search form results - dynamically adding email addresses to contact form 7

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I'm creating a WordPress site where users can search for people (custom post type and taxonomies) and narrow their choices down using a search form (select, radio buttons etc). When the results are shown I want the user to be able to email all the people (custom post type) that are shown in the search results. The email addresses that I need will be entered as a field in each custom post type using 'advanced custom fields'.

When the search form results are shown I can loop through and see all the email addresses but I need to be able to dynamically add these to the 'contact form 7' plugin.

I've found and installed the 'dynamic text extention' plugin but I can't figure out how I would be able to add multiple email addresses that I need.

Any advice would be appreciated!